# What is wrong in chromomap packages and how to change the color and add legend?

Tags: r, colors, legend

Here are my data

chr_anot

```
gene    chr start   end
wnt5    1A  670 900
wnt6    1A  512 635
wnt7    1A  225 315
wnt1    1A  125 400
lala    2A  200 400
BABA    3A  100 150
```

chr_file

```
chr start   end
1A  90  1000
2A  50  500
3A  60  600
```

I run chromomap packages in R studio using this script

```
library(chromoMap) 
chr.data <- read.csv("chr_file.csv", header=T) 
anno.data <- read.csv("chr_anot.csv", header = T) 
chromoMap(list(chr.data),list(anno.data), labels = T, data_based_color_map = T, data_color = list(c(col.set)))
```

However I got a warning message like this:
[image: warning message]

Could anyone tell me what was wrong? I got the result like this.

[image: result]

I also would like to make every gene has different color and add legend. Does anyone know how to make that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning message was caused because of the annotation data.frame, `anno.data`, as it does not have the additional `data` column (5th column in the annotations file, please see the [docs](https://lakshay-anand.github.io/chromoMap/docs.html#Prepare_Input_Data_Files) for input format) while you indicated the chromoMap to color based on the feature-associated data by setting `data_based_color_map` = T.

If you'd like to add a color for each gene, you just need to add a 5th column to your `anno.data` preferably the names of your genes like:

```
anno.data <- cbind.data.frame(anno.data,Symbol=anno$gene)
```

and, then you can create the plot with each gene colored uniquely and create the legend by setting `legend` to `TRUE` and tweaking other arguments to make the plot as desired.

Please have look at how to create discrete color maps for categorical data using chromoMap [here](https://lakshay-anand.github.io/chromoMap/docs.html#chromoMap-DiscreteColorMaps).

Here is something I tried for you:

```
chromoMap(list(chr.data),list(anno.data), 
          # labelling arguments 
          labels = T, 
          label_font = 12,
          label_angle = -55,
          # group annotation arguments
          data_based_color_map = T,
          data_type = "categorical",
          data_colors = list(c("red2","yellow3","blue2","orange3","purple","green2")),
          # for the  legend
          legend = T,
          #adjusting the legend along y-axis
          lg_y = 250,
          #increasing canvas width for legend
          canvas_width = 600,
          #playing with plot properties
          text_font_size = 12,
          chr_color = c("#d3d3d3"))
```

here is the output:

[image: rplot]

You can try a bunch of other configuration options and features offered by `chromoMap`. Please read the [documentation](https://lakshay-anand.github.io/chromoMap/docs.html) for more details.

Disclosure: I am the chromoMap developer

[chromoMap Website](https://lakshay-anand.github.io/chromoMap/index.html)

Comment: OMG, first time I saw your name, I thought it was familiar with me. I never expect that the developer of this packages will help and solve my problem here. Thank you so much! choromoMap is very useful tool for me. Many thanks for your clear explanation and nice output. Have a nice day!

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read the [help], and it's always great to see more experts joining the site.

Comment: To confirm: Stack Overflow does not require disclosure of affiliation when the only links are to official documentation for something which was asked about in the question (and the question wasn't seeded by someone affiliated). We do recommend disclosure of affiliation, for multiple reasons, not the least of which is that people tend to react poorly when they think they see spam. When required, disclosure doesn't need to be formal (e.g. "The docs for my X package are [here]." is fine). Unfortunately, we see a lot of fairly inventive spam, so there can be confusion.

Comment: I do note, however, that it would have been substantially easier to determine that the links were to official documentation if the location of the documentation was listed in the [CRAN entry](https://cran.r-project.org/package=chromoMap) for this package, rather than only having a PDF as a reference manual.